# How to check a variable if it have a value or not?

Tags: vba, excel

**I have a variable which contains a range value which is selected by the user.**

How can I check if it have  a value or not?

I've tried these:

```
If variable_name.Value = Empty then ....

If variable_name.Value = " " then ...
```

But these are only good when the variable contains data like text or numbers or whitespace.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  When is your code failing, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I want to accomplish is a "bad user protection". I want to check if this variable which mentioned is have a value or not. It gets it value in a sub routine, which aims to do a selection in a certain range if the user's double clicks on certain cells. Because if the selection is done, the user presses a button, and then exports the selected data. All of this works fine, I only want to check on button hit, if that variable which should contain the selection range, is containing it or not. By this I can warn the user to make the selection before hitting the button!

Comment: But by the upper code is not good because if I add a watch to that variable which holds the range it writes no value. Not even empty. Still it contains the range.
I hope you understand what I'm trying to say...

Comment: No one can answer this without knowing what type `variable_name` is - depending on the type the answer could be many different things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends what you are testing.

A range object or a cell value?

```
Sub test()

Dim rngObject As Range
Dim value As Variant

    Set rngObject = Sheet1.Range("A1:D5")

    If Not rngObject Is Nothing Then
    'If not nothing then run this code
    End If

    value = rngObject.Cells(1, 1).value
    If Not IsEmpty(value) Then
    'if Not empty then run this code
    End If

    If value <> vbNullString Then
    'if value is not nullstring then run this code
    End If


End Sub
```