# User defined function which accepts both continuous and discontinuous ranges in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, input, user-defined-functions, vba

#### Base problem

I'm trying to make my own VBA functions in Excel and I want it to be able to accept essentially any kind of input and treat the input as a vector, but I haven't figured out how to do so for both continuous (e.g. (A1:A10) or (A1:R1)) and discontinuous (e.g. (A1;B5;G12)) ranges. I can make the functions work for either, but not for both types at the same time.

The reason I wish to do this is that I wish to make my own versions of AVERAGE and STDEV.S where it can handle #N/A values in the cells. I know that I can use AVERAGEIF(range;"<>#N/A") in order to do so for averages, but AVERAGEIF does not allow me to use discontinuous ranges and, as far as I know, there are no such alternative for STDEV.S.

#### Background on my data

My data is obtained from several samples which I have measured by various chemical means. I have prepared one sample per day and then spent the rest of the day measuring stuff on it. Each sample is considered "one experiment" and each experiment is stored as individual worksheets in which I store data from all different analysis methods and do any data treatment to make the data comparable (e.g. calculates molarity from molality, do adjustments for temperature differences, etc); I also store a lot of semi irrelevant information (such as notes that are not required for the final results, but which are still required to keep). Long story short, it's far too much data to have all runs stored in one worksheet as it would make it too messy to look at and too messy to treat individual experiments, especially whenever I add a new experiment to the pile of data; my current method allows me to simply copy an existing worksheet and pasting new data into the old equations. The treated data is then linked to an "overview" worksheet where I list the most interesting data structured in such way that I can easily compare the values from different measurements. The linking is done with an INDIRECT so that I can easily add new information from new experiments. Since the data comes from experiments, then there are bound to be data missing and I use #N/A to cover such holes as linking from one worksheet to another produces a "0" if the data is missing. I know I could replace the #N/A with a simple dash (-) or something similar, which will make the built in AVERAGE and STDEV.S work, but I want to use the same arrays of data for plotting and it appears as if only #N/A will remove the data point from the plot as the graphing in excel treats a dash as a zero value.

The data on my "overview" worksheet is arranged as

```
    Date    pH    Na+ conc    K+ conc  ...lots of other variables
    Date 1  7.4     140        3       ... 
    Date 2  7.1     #N/A       4       ...
    ....    ...     ...        ...     ...
    Date N  7.3     143        3.5     ...
```

#### Code which works for continuous ranges

What I have managed to do so far, which supports continuous ranges, is the following code example which calculates the standard deviation of cells which contain #N/A values. This code works perfectly when I select a whole column (or continuous part of a column), but not if i select discontinuous range of cells.

```
Function StdevNaN_S(xRange)

'Sample Standard deviation which excludes NaN values

xR = xRange 'I can, for some strange reason, not use UBound unless I re-store the data in xR...
NoE1 = UBound(xR, 1) 'Number of Elements along dimension 1 (columns)
NoE2 = UBound(xR, 2) 'Number of Elements along dimension 2 (rows)
NoE = NoE1 * NoE2 'Total Number of Elements (this way makes it work regardless of row or column range)

'Need to first calculate the NaN excluded average value - could use the AVERAGEIF to simplify, but that will break if the range is discontinuous
xSum = 0
xAmount = 0
For N = 1 To NoE
    If IsNumeric(xRange(N)) Then
        xSum = xSum + xRange(N)
        xAmount = xAmount + 1 'counting how many cells that are used in the sum, used as the divisor in the average and the variance expression. Couldn't use the "CountIf" expression as it counted cells which contained text
    Else
    End If
Next N
xAvg = xSum / xAmount

'Uses the average in the variance calculation
xSum = 0
For N = 1 To NoE
    If IsNumeric(xRange(N)) Then
        xSum = xSum + (xRange(N) - xAvg) ^ 2 'Summing up (x - x_avg) ^ 2, which is the dividend of the variance expression
    Else
    End If
Next N

StdevNaN_S = (xSum / (xAmount - 1)) ^ 0.5 'the sample standard deviation is the square root of the corrected variance

End Function
```

My problem is that I wish to make averages and standard deviation calculations for parts of the data. Such as the sample produced on e.g., Date 1, 5, 19 and 34 was produced with a particular stock of chemicals, while Date 2:4, 6:11 and 25:33 from a second stock and the rest from a third one, so I wish to know if there are any influences of the specific stocks.

#### Code which works for discontinuous ranges

I found an example on [cpaerson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx) which showed how to allow a function to take discontinuous ranges and treat it as a vector. Their example is

```
Function SumOf(ParamArray Nums() As Variant) As Variant
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Add up the numbers in Nums
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim N As Long
    Dim D As Double
    For N = LBound(Nums) To UBound(Nums)
        If IsNumeric(Nums(N)) = True Then
            D = D + Nums(N)
        Else
            SumOf = CVErr(xlErrNum)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next N
    SumOf = D
End Function
```

However, this function works **only** for discontinuous selections - it works just as it should if I select e.g., (A1;A5;A19;A34) or (A1;A2;A3;...;A34) but it gives me an error if I select (A1:A34).

#### Question

How should I code my function so that I can select whichever cells I want and then use their content for calculations?

Comment: Not a full answer but check out the Areas property of a range and build in a check in your function to count the number of areas. If 1, press on, if >1 loop through each area and combine into a single array. Possibly a bit of a faff, some clever soul here may have a bright idea.

Comment: You can also pass your range of continuous and discontinuous ranges as a string to the UDF and then parse the string yourself for `;` (as seems to be the case for your regional setup) and `:`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - what you both (@SJR & @ Ralph) describe is exactly what I would like to do. My problem is still that I'm not skilled enough in VBA to actually write the code for it :/

Comment: Have a look at this earlier question and see if it sheds any light http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365547/non-contiguous-named-range-into-an-array-then-into-row-in-different-sheet

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out how to sort the data so that the function can handle both continuous and discontinuous ranges, a lot thanks to the comments on the question from SJR and Ralph, as well as from the [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110220/7145651).

The way to allow discontinuous ranges is with an ParamArray and then go through all parameters entered and check what they contain (this is where I initially failed as I didn't know how to make Excel check the content of each parameter I fed to the function). The tricky part is that if the parameter it currently checks contains only one cell, then the way it needs to be treated is different compared to how it should be treated if it contains a continuous range.

E.g., checking all parameters from the ParamArray will fail if one uses UBound on a parameter containing only one cell. Additionally, in order to properly address each cell in a continuous range in a parameter, then one needs to loop through InputParameters(i).Cells(j), whereas if the parameter is just a single cell, then it is enough to address it as InputParameters(i).

The code I produced now works as I wanted it; I can select any range of cells and calculate both the standard deviation and the average while excluding NaN values. I compared it to the built in STDEV.S, STDEV.P and AVERAGE and it produces the exact same result*. I have not clue why the built in functions does not exclude NaN values as default, but I include the code for the functions below for anyone who want to use it.

#### Code for STDEV.S which excludes NaN values

```
Function NaNStdev_S(ParamArray xRange() As Variant) As Double
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'A function to calculate the sample standard deviation of any ranges of cells
'while excluding text, logicals, empty cells and cells containing #N/A.
'Can handle both continuous and discontinuous ranges.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim CellsUsed As Integer
Dim NumArg As Integer
Dim NumCell As Integer
Dim xAvg As Double
Dim xSum As Double
Dim xTemp As Variant
Dim xVect() As String

NumArg = UBound(xRange) 'Counts the number of input arguments (i.e., number of discontinuous regions)

For i = 0 To NumArg 'Goes through each discontinuous region
    xTemp = xRange(i) 'Stores the current region in a temporary variable as several of the later operations cannot be performed on the full input array
    If IsArray(xTemp) Then 'Checks if the current region is an array; if yes, then that array will be continuous
        NumCell = UBound(xTemp, 1) * UBound(xTemp, 2) 'Checks how many cells are in the array
            For j = 1 To NumCell 'Goes through all cells in the current region
                If IsEmpty(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf Application.IsLogical(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'If the content of the cell is numeric, then use it
                    xSum = xSum + xRange(i).Cells(j) 'Add the current cell value to the sum of all cell values
                    CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Counts how many of the cell values that are actually used
                    ReDim Preserve xVect(CellsUsed) 'Adjusts the size of xVect
                    xVect(CellsUsed) = xRange(i).Cells(j) 'Reformats all usable values into one single vector for later use
                Else
                End If
            Next j
    Else 'If the current region is not an array, then it's just a single value
        If IsEmpty(xRange(i)) Then 'do nothing
        ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i)) Then 'If the content of the current region is numeric, then use it
            xSum = xSum + xRange(i) 'Add the current cell (region) value to the sum of all cell values
            CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Increase the counter of used values
            ReDim Preserve xVect(CellsUsed) 'Adjusts the size of xVect
            xVect(CellsUsed) = xRange(i) 'Adds the current value into the reformatted vector for later use
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next i

xAvg = xSum / CellsUsed 'Average of all cells which contains numbers

xSum = 0 'resets the sum as it's no longer needed
For i = 1 To CellsUsed 'Goes through the reformatted vector and calculates the sum of (x - x_avg) ^ 2
    xSum = xSum + (xVect(i) - xAvg) ^ 2 'This is the dividend of the variance equation
Next i

NaNStdev_S = (xSum / (CellsUsed - 1)) ^ 0.5 'the sample standard deviation is the square root of the corrected variance

End Function
```

#### Code for STDEV.P which excludes NaN values

```
Function NaNStdev_P(ParamArray xRange() As Variant) As Double
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'A function to calculate the population standard deviation of any ranges of cells
'while excluding text, logicals, empty cells and cells containing #N/A.
'Can handle both continuous and discontinuous ranges.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim CellsUsed As Integer
Dim NumArg As Integer
Dim NumCell As Integer
Dim xAvg As Double
Dim xSum As Double
Dim xTemp As Variant
Dim xVect() As String

NumArg = UBound(xRange) 'Counts the number of input arguments (i.e., number of discontinuous regions)

For i = 0 To NumArg 'Goes through each discontinuous region
    xTemp = xRange(i) 'Stores the current region in a temporary variable as several of the later operations cannot be performed on the full input array
    If IsArray(xTemp) Then 'Checks if the current region is an array; if yes, then that array will be continuous
        NumCell = UBound(xTemp, 1) * UBound(xTemp, 2) 'Checks how many cells are in the array
            For j = 1 To NumCell 'Goes through all cells in the current region
                If IsEmpty(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf Application.IsLogical(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'If the content of the cell is numeric, then use it
                    xSum = xSum + xRange(i).Cells(j) 'Add the current cell value to the sum of all cell values
                    CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Counts how many of the cell values that are actually used
                    ReDim Preserve xVect(CellsUsed) 'Adjusts the size of xVect
                    xVect(CellsUsed) = xRange(i).Cells(j) 'Reformats all usable values into one single vector for later use
                Else
                End If
            Next j
    Else 'If the current region is not an array, then it's just a single value
        If IsEmpty(xRange(i)) Then 'do nothing
        ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i)) Then 'If the content of the current region is numeric, then use it
            xSum = xSum + xRange(i) 'Add the current cell (region) value to the sum of all cell values
            CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Increase the counter of used values
            ReDim Preserve xVect(CellsUsed) 'Adjusts the size of xVect
            xVect(CellsUsed) = xRange(i) 'Adds the current value into the reformatted vector for later use
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next i

xAvg = xSum / CellsUsed 'Average of all cells which contains numbers

xSum = 0 'resets the sum as it's no longer needed
For i = 1 To CellsUsed 'Goes through the reformatted vector and calculates the sum of (x - x_avg) ^ 2
    xSum = xSum + (xVect(i) - xAvg) ^ 2 'This is the dividend of the variance equation
Next i

NaNStdev_P = (xSum / CellsUsed) ^ 0.5  'the population standard deviation is the square root of the variance

End Function
```

#### Code for AVERAGE which excludes NaN values

```
Function NaNAverage(ParamArray xRange() As Variant) As Double
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'A function to calculate the average of any ranges of cells
'while excluding text, logicals, empty cells and cells containing #N/A.
'Can handle both continuous and discontinuous ranges.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim CellsUsed As Integer
Dim NumArg As Integer
Dim NumCell As Integer
Dim xSum As Double
Dim xTemp As Variant

NumArg = UBound(xRange) 'Counts the number of input arguments (i.e., number of discontinuous regions)

For i = 0 To NumArg 'Goes through each discontinuous region
    xTemp = xRange(i) 'Stores the current region in a temporary variable as several of the later operations cannot be performed on the full input array
    If IsArray(xTemp) Then 'Checks if the current region is an array; if yes, then that array will be continuous
        NumCell = UBound(xTemp, 1) * UBound(xTemp, 2) 'Checks how many cells are in the array
            For j = 1 To NumCell 'Goes through all cells in the current region
                If IsEmpty(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf Application.IsLogical(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'do nothing
                ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i).Cells(j)) Then 'If the content of the cell is numeric, then use it
                    xSum = xSum + xRange(i).Cells(j) 'Add the current cell value to the sum of all cell values
                    CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Counts how many of the cell values that are actually used
                Else
                End If
            Next j
    Else 'If the current region is not an array, then it's just a single value
        If IsEmpty(xRange(i)) Then 'do nothing
        ElseIf IsNumeric(xRange(i)) Then 'If the content of the current region is numeric, then use it
            xSum = xSum + xRange(i) 'Add the current cell (region) value to the sum of all cell values
            CellsUsed = CellsUsed + 1 'Increase the counter of used values
        Else
        End If
    End If
Next i

NaNAverage = xSum / CellsUsed 'Average of all cells which contains numbers

End Function
```

#### *Disclaimer

I mentioned that the code produces exactly the same value as the built in function - however, I did notice one occasion when it did not.
I placed the following randomly chosen values as randomly sized and positioned ranges in my Excel sheet:

```
(00:01:00, -10, -33, 10, 33, 20, 66, 30, 40, 300, TRUE, {empty cell} , #N/A)
```

If they are randomly distributed (i.e., I placed them in the following cells (P22:Q23;R22:R23;S22:T22;S21:V21;Q28)), then they differ from the value which STDEV.S produces (I have manually excluded the cell with #N/A from the STDEV.S function), but they only differ on the 13th decimal (my function gives 93.5950714912684, while STDEV.S gives 93.5950714912683), which should be a small enough error to be irrelevant. Funny thing is, if I place all of the values as one row (i.e., I place all of the values on e.g. (M34:Y34)) then both my function and the built in function gives exactly the same result (i.e., 93.5950714912683). The error seems to stem from the cell containing 1 minute; if I change 00:01:00 to any other time value (such as 00:01:01 or 01:01:00), then both functions yields exactly the same result regardless if the values are placed on a row or as randomly distributed regions on the worksheet.

I cannot explain this odd behaviour, but so far it seems to be producing only an insignificant error, so I will assume that my code is working as intended.